# Asterisk Server - System(asterisk -rx 'sip reload')

Tags: asterisk

I have the following line in extensions.conf

exten => s,1,System(asterisk -rx 'sip reload')

Is there a SipReload() command in asterisk that can replace my System() command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above method is the only way I've ever seen it done, providing you write in some kind of protection so someone can't just hit that context in your dial-plan and have fun reloading your server over and over ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find out would be to do from the Asterisk CLI:

```
asterisk -rx'core show applications'
```

The output currently does not show any such option. The output is:
    -= Registered Asterisk Applications =-

```
          ADSIProg: Load Asterisk ADSI Scripts into phone 
               AGI: Executes an AGI compliant application. 
               AMD: Attempt to detect answering machines. 
            Answer: Answer a channel if ringing. 
      Authenticate: Authenticate a user 
        BackGround: Play an audio file while waiting for digits of an extension to go to. 
  BackgroundDetect: Background a file with talk detect. 
            Bridge: Bridge two channels. 
        BridgeWait: Put a call into the holding bridge. 
              Busy: Indicate the Busy condition.
CallCompletionCancel: Cancel call completion service
  CallCompletionRequest: Request call completion service for previous call 
     CELGenUserEvent: Generates a CEL User Defined Event. 
     ChangeMonitor: Change monitoring filename of a channel. 
       ChanIsAvail: Check channel availability 
   ChannelRedirect: Redirects given channel to a dialplan target 
           ChanSpy: Listen to a channel, and optionally whisper into it. 
         ClearHash: Clear the keys from a specified hashname. 
        ConfBridge: Conference bridge application. 
        Congestion: Indicate the Congestion condition. 
     ContinueWhile: Restart a While loop. 
   ControlPlayback: Play a file with fast forward and rewind. 
          DAHDIRAS: Executes DAHDI ISDN RAS application. 
         DAHDIScan: Scan DAHDI channels to monitor calls. 
          DateTime: Says a specified time in a custom format. 
             DBdel: Delete a key from the asterisk database. 
         DBdeltree: Delete a family or keytree from the asterisk database. 
           DeadAGI: Executes AGI on a hungup channel. 
              Dial: Attempt to connect to another device or endpoint and bridge the call. 
           Dictate: Virtual Dictation Machine. 
         Directory: Provide directory of voicemail extensions. 
              DISA: Direct Inward System Access. 
          DumpChan: Dump Info About The Calling Channel. 
              EAGI: Executes an EAGI compliant application. 
              Echo: Echo media, DTMF back to the calling party 
          EndWhile: End a while loop. 
              Exec: Executes dialplan application. 
            ExecIf: Executes dialplan application, conditionally. 
        ExecIfTime: Conditional application execution based on the current time. 
         ExitWhile: End a While loop. 
          ExtenSpy: Listen to a channel, and optionally whisper into it. 
       ExternalIVR: Interfaces with an external IVR application. 
             Flash: Flashes a DAHDI Trunk. 
           ForkCDR: Forks the current Call Data Record for this channel. 
          GetCPEID: Get ADSI CPE ID. 
             Gosub: Jump to label, saving return address. 
           GosubIf: Conditionally jump to label, saving return address. 
              Goto: Jump to a particular priority, extension, or context. 
            GotoIf: Conditional goto. 
        GotoIfTime: Conditional Goto based on the current time. 
            Hangup: Hang up the calling channel. 
  HangupCauseClear: Clears hangup cause information from the channel that is available through HANGUPCAUSE. 
              ICES: Encode and stream using 'ices'. 
         ImportVar: Import a variable from a channel into a new variable. 
        Incomplete: Returns AST_PBX_INCOMPLETE value. 
               Log: Send arbitrary text to a selected log level. 
             Macro: Macro Implementation. 
    MacroExclusive: Exclusive Macro Implementation. 
         MacroExit: Exit from Macro. 
           MacroIf: Conditional Macro implementation. 
     MailboxExists: Check to see if Voicemail mailbox exists. 
       MessageSend: Send a text message. 
         Milliwatt: Generate a Constant 1004Hz tone at 0dbm (mu-law). 
     MinivmAccMess: Record account specific messages. 
      MinivmDelete: Delete Mini-Voicemail voicemail messages. 
       MinivmGreet: Play Mini-Voicemail prompts. 
         MinivmMWI: Send Message Waiting Notification to subscriber(s) of mailbox. 
      MinivmNotify: Notify voicemail owner about new messages. 
      MinivmRecord: Receive Mini-Voicemail and forward via e-mail. 
        MixMonitor: Record a call and mix the audio during the recording.  Use of StopMixMonitor is required to guarantee the audio file is available for processing during dialplan execution. 
           Monitor: Monitor a channel. 
         Morsecode: Plays morse code. 
         MP3Player: Play an MP3 file or M3U playlist file or stream. 
              MSet: Set channel variable(s) or function value(s). 
       MusicOnHold: Play Music On Hold indefinitely. 
            NBScat: Play an NBS local stream. 
             NoCDR: Tell Asterisk to not maintain a CDR for this channel. 
              NoOp: Do Nothing (No Operation). 
         Originate: Originate a call. 
              Page: Page series of phones 
      PauseMonitor: Pause monitoring of a channel. 
            Pickup: Directed extension call pickup. 
        PickupChan: Pickup a ringing channel. 
          Playback: Play a file. 
         PlayTones: Play a tone list. 
    PrivacyManager: Require phone number to be entered, if no CallerID sent 
        Proceeding: Indicate proceeding. 
          Progress: Indicate progress. 
    RaiseException: Handle an exceptional condition. 
              Read: Read a variable. 
         ReadExten: Read an extension into a variable. 
        ReceiveFAX: Receive a FAX and save as a TIFF/F file. 
            Record: Record to a file. 
          ResetCDR: Resets the Call Data Record. 
         RetryDial: Place a call, retrying on failure allowing an optional exit extension. 
            Return: Return from gosub routine. 
           Ringing: Indicate ringing tone. 
          SayAlpha: Say Alpha. 
      SayAlphaCase: Say Alpha. 
         SayDigits: Say Digits. 
         SayNumber: Say Number. 
       SayPhonetic: Say Phonetic. 
       SayUnixTime: Says a specified time in a custom format. 
          SendDTMF: Sends arbitrary DTMF digits 
           SendFAX: Sends a specified TIFF/F file as a FAX. 
         SendImage: Sends an image file. 
          SendText: Send a Text Message. 
           SendURL: Send a URL. 
               Set: Set channel variable or function value. 
       SetAMAFlags: Set the AMA Flags. 
      SIPAddHeader: Add a SIP header to the outbound call. 
       SIPDtmfMode: Change the dtmfmode for a SIP call. 
   SIPRemoveHeader: Remove SIP headers previously added with SIPAddHeader 
               SMS: Communicates with SMS service centres and SMS capable analogue phones. 
        SoftHangup: Hangs up the requested channel. 
SpeechActivateGrammar: Activate a grammar. 
  SpeechBackground: Play a sound file and wait for speech to be recognized. 
      SpeechCreate: Create a Speech Structure. 
SpeechDeactivateGrammar: Deactivate a grammar. 
     SpeechDestroy: End speech recognition. 
 SpeechLoadGrammar: Load a grammar. 
SpeechProcessingSound: Change background processing sound. 
       SpeechStart: Start recognizing voice in the audio stream. 
SpeechUnloadGrammar: Unload a grammar. 
          StackPop: Remove one address from gosub stack. 
  StartMusicOnHold: Play Music On Hold. 
            Stasis: Invoke an external Stasis application.
    StopMixMonitor: Stop recording a call through MixMonitor, and free the recording's file handle. 
       StopMonitor: Stop monitoring a channel. 
   StopMusicOnHold: Stop playing Music On Hold. 
     StopPlayTones: Stop playing a tone list. 
            System: Execute a system command. 
        TestClient: Execute Interface Test Client. 
        TestServer: Execute Interface Test Server. 
          Transfer: Transfer caller to remote extension. 
           TryExec: Executes dialplan application, always returning. 
         TrySystem: Try executing a system command. 
    UnpauseMonitor: Unpause monitoring of a channel. 
         UserEvent: Send an arbitrary user-defined event to parties interested in a channel (AMI users and relevant res_stasis applications). 
           Verbose: Send arbitrary text to verbose output. 
    VMAuthenticate: Authenticate with Voicemail passwords. 
         VMSayName: Play the name of a voicemail user 
         VoiceMail: Leave a Voicemail message. 
     VoiceMailMain: Check Voicemail messages. 
  VoiceMailPlayMsg: Play a single voice mail msg from a mailbox by msg id. 
              Wait: Waits for some time. 
         WaitExten: Waits for an extension to be entered. 
      WaitForNoise: Waits for a specified amount of noise. 
       WaitForRing: Wait for Ring Application. 
    WaitForSilence: Waits for a specified amount of silence. 
         WaitUntil: Wait (sleep) until the current time is the given epoch. 
             While: Start a while loop. 
        Zapateller: Block telemarketers with SIT. 
-= 153 Applications Registered =-
```